# Subquery returned more than one value... in sql query, What that means?, and what is wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I got this message if the query seems right: 
**"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
"** But when I try the query splitted it works fine, I mean, what could happen?

and this is the query :

```
UPDATE llantas_dictamen_scrap
   SET clave_operador =
       (SELECT REPLACE(scrap, '-', '') as clave_operador
          FROM (SELECT RIGHT(clave_operador, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(clave_operador), 1)) as scrap
                  FROM llantas_dictamen_scrap) t
       )
```

Of course I'm returning more than one one value, What that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE llantas_dictamen_scrap
SET clave_operador = RIGHT(clave_operador, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(clave_operador), 1) -1)
WHERE CHARINDEX('-',clave_operador, 1) > 0
```

This one adjusts the position of the call to RIGHT, excluding the  '-' we found. There's no need to make a call to REPLACE, because once we know the position of the last trailing '-' , we can just excluding by taking the right-most characters (-1 for its position).

You can't return multiple values for a single row. You are updating multiple rows, yes, for FOR EACH ROW, you are giving clave_operador a single value.

Comment: I got this when I run it **"Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.The statement has been terminated."**

Comment: Are there records where clave_operador field does not have a hyphen in it? then add WHERE CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(clave_operador), 1) > 0. This will only update those select records with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a single column value equal to more than one column value. If you want to update using the same query your using you have to specify which column you want to use. If you specify to select top 1... with order by that should give you a usable single subquery result for your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have 
Table A

> Col A     Col B  Col C
>   1          2           3
>   1          2           3

And you try

> *Update* Table A *Set* Col B = (select 5 union select 6)

We won't know if we need to set Column B to 5 or 6, so we get an error.

You need to make sure your sub query only returns one value, one easy way would be to do the following to your subquery (notice the Top 1).

`SELECT Top 1 REPLACE(scrap, '-', '')as clave_operador FROM (SELECT RIGHT(clave_operador, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(clave_operador),1))as scrap FROM llantas_dictamen_scrap)t`

Answer (score 0):

what that means this message java.lang.ClassNotFoundExeption:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
and this is my code in jform
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
String Number  = txt_idinf.getText();
String Name  = txt_Name.getText();
String Birthdate  = txt_Birthdate.getText();
String Cas  = txt_Cas.getText();
String Helth  = txt_Helth.getText();
String Sourc  = txt_Sourc.getText();
String Children  = txt_Children.getText();
String Adresse  = txt_Adresse.getText();
String PhoneNumber  = txt_PhoneNumber.getText();
String Demande  = txt_Demande.getText();
String Procédurs  = txt_Procédurs.getText();
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
try{
Class.forName ("com.myql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/infocarte","root","root");
pstm = conn.prepareStatement("insert into information values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pstm.setString(1, Number);
pstm.setString(2, Name);
pstm.setString(3, Birthdate);
pstm.setString(4, Cas);
pstm.setString(5, Helth);
pstm.setString(6, Sourc);
pstm.setString(7, Children);
pstm.setString(8, Adresse);
pstm.setString(9, PhoneNumber);
pstm.setString(10, Demande);
pstm.setString(11, Procédurs);
int i = pstm.executeUpdate();
if (i>0){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "تم حفظ البيانات");
}
else{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "خطأ في حفظ البيانات");   
}}

catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);  
}

}
```

Comment: Im not sure this really answers the question.  Im pretty sure the poster didnt specify a language.